# Inner Join two databases to import data - SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, inner-join

I've created a Winforms app in C#. I do have both my Datasources listed as Datasets.

- LOTSDataSet = Source Info
- webbitdbdataset = Destination Dataset.

These are connected with `LOTSConnectionString` and `WebbitConnectionString`.

Anyway I have the code shown below that I am getting a connection error on, when I try to import data from LOTS to Webbit.

```
SqlConnection lotscon = new SqlConnection(PackChecker.Properties.Settings.Default["LOTSConnectionString"].ToString());

using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(PackChecker.Properties.Settings.Default["WebbitConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
    string strgetloc = @"INSERT INTO tblinstitution ( 
dispenseinstid, institutionname )
SELECT NEWinstitution.institutionid, NEWinstitution.institutionname
FROM NEWinstitution LEFT JOIN tblinstitution ON NEWinstitution.institutionid 
= tblinstitution.dispenseinstid
WHERE (((tblinstitution.institutionid) Is Null));";

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strgetloc, con))
    {
        lotscon.Open();
        con.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
        lotscon.Close();
    }
}
```

Trying to "OPEN CONNECTION" for both connections was just something I tried.. I guess knowing it was going to fail, but I wanted to try before I asked on here.

The command is attached to the OLEDB connection to Webbit, thus I'm getting an exception based on 'cannot find LOTS server'

Prior to running the query I do run a connection checker, which opens both connections and "tries and catches" both connections to make sure they are valid connections.

Using Access the query does work, so I know the issue 100% is trying to open these connections to two databases!

Any direction would be appreciated.
Gangel

Comment: Should i be exporting on set of data (perhaps LOTS) as a dataset, then connecting the dataset as an inner join to my Webbit one?

Comment: Also, the string above works on the PC im building this with, but NOT on a different laptop..